# Getting a DrawingContext for a wpf WriteableBitmap

Tags: wpf, bitmap, drawing

Is there a way to get a `DrawingContext` (or something similar) for a `WriteableBitmap`?  I.e. something to allow you to call simple `DrawLine`/`DrawRectangle`/etc kinds of methods, rather than manipulate the raw pixels directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears [the word is no](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/84299fec-94a1-49a1-b3bc-ec48b8bdf04f/).

---

For future reference, we plan to use a port of the [Writeable Bitmap Extensions](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) for WPF.

For a solution using purely existing code, any of the other suggestions mentioned below will work.

Comment: That's no official word. That's just some guy saying something on a forum.

Comment: Point taken; updated text. I suppose you could say it meant "official" as in "posted to a forum monitored by officials, and not corrected by them", but that is a bit of a stretch :)

Answer (score 22):

I found sixlettervariables' solution the most workable one. However, there's a "drawingContext.Close()" missing. According to MSDN, "A DrawingContext must be closed before its content can be rendered".
The result is the following utility function:

```
public static BitmapSource CreateBitmap(
    int width, int height, double dpi, Action<DrawingContext> render)
{
    DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
    {
        render(drawingContext);
    }
    RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        width, height, dpi, dpi, PixelFormats.Default);
    bitmap.Render(drawingVisual);

    return bitmap;
}
```

This can then easily be used like this:

```
BitmapSource image = ImageTools.CreateBitmap(
    320, 240, 96,
    drawingContext =>
    {
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
            Brushes.Green, null, new Rect(50, 50, 200, 100));
        drawingContext.DrawLine(
            new Pen(Brushes.White, 2), new Point(0, 0), new Point(320, 240));
    });
```

Comment: The `.Close()` is implicit in the `.Dispose()` - which is the whole point behind the `using` statement.  If you leave *only* the `render(...)` command inside the using block, you'll be fine and don't need any `.Close()`.

Comment: There's no `WriteableBitmap` in this answer, why is it the top one? :) It's completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: My guess is that it's upvoted because the original question may be akin to asking "How do I turn this screw with this hammer?" and the answer is "Use a screwdriver" instead of how to use the hammer to do it.

Comment: if you want to make WritableBitmap from it you can simply call: `WritaBleBitmap result = new WritableBitmap(image);`

Answer (score 18):

If you don't mind using [`System.Drawing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) you could do something like:

```
var wb = new WriteableBitmap( width, height, dpi, dpi, 
                              PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null );
wb.Lock();
var bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap( wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight,
                                     wb.BackBufferStride, 
                                     PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb, 
                                     wb.BackBuffer );

Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage( bmp ); // Good old Graphics

g.DrawLine( ... ); // etc...

// ...and finally:
g.Dispose(); 
bmp.Dispose();
wb.AddDirtyRect( ... );
wb.Unlock();
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it out just yet, but this seems like a very reasonable workaround in WPF. Thanks!

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering, I tested the DrawingVisual WPF method mentioned in this topic and this System.Drawing method, and this System.Drawing method is MUCH FASTER.  I'm very disappointed in WPF.

Comment: You can do the same thing with WPF, with similar (or better?) performance by using RenderTargetBitmap and DrawingVisual / DrawingContext

Answer (score 5):

I'm wondering the same thing, as currently I do something like:

```
DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
{
   //
   // ... draw on the drawingContext
   //
   RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, dpi, dpi, PixelFormats.Default);
   bmp.Render(drawingVisual);
   image.Source = bmp;
}
```

I'm trying to use the WriteableBitmap to allow multithreaded access to the pixel buffer, which is currently not allowed with neither a DrawingContext nor a RenderTargetBitmap. Maybe some sort of WritePixels routine based off of what you've retrieved from the RenderTargetBitmap would work?

Comment: Render spend too long

Comment: You cant write the  bmp.Render in using that cant get the drawingVisual.

Comment: You may need to `bmp.Freeze()` if you're sharing the bitmap between threads.

Answer (score 1):

A different way to solve this problem is to use a `RenderTargetBitmap` as a backing store, just like in the `WriteableBitmap` example. Then you can create and issue WPF drawing commands to it whenever you want. For example:

```
// create the backing store in a constructor
var backingStore = 
      new RenderTargetBitmap(200,200,97,97,PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
myImage.Source = backingStore;

// whenever you want to update the bitmap, do:
var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
var drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
{
    // your drawing commands go here
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
            Brushes.Red, new Pen(),
            new Rect(this.RenderSize));
}
Render(drawingContext);
drawingContext.Close();
backingStore.Render(drawingVisual);
```

If you want to redraw this `RenderTargetBitmap` every frame, you can catch the `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event, like this:

```
CompositionTarget.Rendering += MyRenderingHandler;
```