# Using gdi+ with InteropBitmap

Tags: wpf, gdi+, writeablebitmap

Is it possible to use WPF's InteropBitmap together with gdi+ ? Any examples ?

(I need it for 2D drawing, many small objects; I know how to use gdi+ with WriteableBitmap => [(see post by Danko)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88488/getting-a-drawingcontext-for-a-wpf-writeablebitmap) , but after all I've read InteropBitmap should be faster)

fritz

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid using InteropBitmap for the time being and with this kind of task. I don't think the performance increase would be all you're hoping it to be, especially with the [memory leak](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/603004/massive-gpu-memory-leak-with-interopbitmap) that requires you constantly calling GC.Collect(). If you said you were doing Direct2D instead of GDI+, I would see more of a reason to attempt going this route.

Is the GDI+ 2D drawing you need to do something that can't be ported over to DrawingContext's methods? In my experience, this has been the easiest and fastest route to porting GDI+ stuf to WPF.

Comment: It could be ported, but it's much slower because of may small text items that must be rendered...In the meantime i have found the fastest solution for my scenario: System.Drawing.BufferedGraphics and a WinForms Picturebox on a windowsformshost inside a wpf app.