# Drawing line using WPF WriteableBitmap.BackBuffer

Tags: wpf, writeablebitmap

Do you know any library that provides methods to draw simple shapes (lines and optionally other shapes) using WPF WriteableBitmap and ideally BackBuffer?
I know that there is a WriteableBitmapEx project for silverlight but is there WPF equivalent?

Comment: Related: [How to get a DrawingContext for a WriteableBitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88488/getting-a-drawingcontext-for-a-wpf-writeablebitmap)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess here is the answer to my question :)

```
_plotBitmap.Lock();

var b = new Bitmap(_plotBitmap.PixelWidth,
                   _plotBitmap.PixelHeight,
                   _plotBitmap.BackBufferStride,
                   System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, 
                   _plotBitmap.BackBuffer);

using(var bitmapGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(b))
{
    bitmapGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
    bitmapGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
    bitmapGraphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
    bitmapGraphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
    bitmapGraphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gold,2,2,222,222);
}

_plotBitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0,0,_plotBitmap.PixelWidth,_plotBitmap.PixelHeight));
_plotBitmap.Unlock();
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly Dispose() the bitmap. This is what using is designed for.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using Bitmap, but asking for a solution using WriteableBitmap. There is a WriteableBitmapEx for WPF.

Comment: WriteableBitmapEx has not optimal perfomance, and cannot draw text; it has better antialias system for lines only, if you need in it.