# How can draw strokes over each other with opacity using a inkPresenter?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to use an inkpresenter so that each new stroke is laid above the previous ones creating a darken effect.

I have tried creating a new inkpresenter each time and adding it to a canvas, but the opacity effect only appears after I release the mouse. I want it to immediatly show as you are drawing. If I set the inkpresenter diretly to the content of the target element (no blending), the strokes have opacity as you draw.

Comment: Please add some code how you are using `InkPresenter` inyour code. I wrote a simple test application and it seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted any code showing how you are currently handling InkPresenter in your application. I've made a quick test program in WPf and it seems to work correctly with opacity.

I placed `InkPresenter` control in xaml and added `PreviewMouseDown`, `PreviewMouseMove` and `PreviewMouseUp` methods' handler to the code behind. The code I used  to handle those events looks like this:

```
System.Windows.Ink.Stroke newStroke = null;

    private void inkPresenterSample_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        inkPresenterSample.CaptureMouse();

        //get mouse position and add first point to a new line to be drawn
        var mousePosition = e.GetPosition(inkPresenterSample);
        var stylusStartPoint = new StylusPointCollection();
        stylusStartPoint.Add(new StylusPoint(mousePosition.X, mousePosition.Y));

        //set line's attributes, it real application this should be probably done outside this method
        var drawingAttributes = new System.Windows.Ink.DrawingAttributes();
        //IMPORTANT: semi-transparent color is used, so the opacity effect is visible
        drawingAttributes.Color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(110, 0, 0, 0);
        drawingAttributes.Width = 10;

        //create a new stroke to be drawn
        newStroke = new System.Windows.Ink.Stroke(stylusStartPoint, drawingAttributes);
        newStroke.StylusPoints.Add(new StylusPoint(mousePosition.X, mousePosition.Y));

        //add reference to a new stroke to the InkPresenter control
        inkPresenterSample.Strokes.Add(newStroke);
    }

    private void inkPresenterSample_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        inkPresenterSample.ReleaseMouseCapture();

        if (newStroke != null)
        {
            newStroke = null;
        }
    }

    private void inkPresenterSample_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //if a stroke is currently drawn in the InkPresenter
        if (newStroke != null)
        {
            //add a new point to the stroke
            var mousePosition = e.GetPosition(inkPresenterSample);
            newStroke.StylusPoints.Add(new StylusPoint(mousePosition.X, mousePosition.Y));
        }
    }
```

It seems to work as you described and I can see the darker parts of lines where few of them are overlapping.

**Update**

The overlapping effect in the suggested solution works for several overlapping lines, but does not work if a single line overlapps itself. If you want to make it work in this case as well, you can try to:

- use `Canvas` and add `Polyline` elements on it (**update**: this seems to work like the first solution suggested, so one line overlapping does not give the opacity effect)
- take a look at drawing on `Image` element using `DrawingContext` described here, it may help: [Drawing with mouse causes gaps between pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869668/drawing-with-mouse-causes-gaps-between-pixels/8869814#8869814)

Comment: thanks a ton! your code really works. The main differences I think are that I was adding the stroke on mouseup instead of mousedown and that I was setting drawingattributes on the inkpresenter instead of the stroke.