# howto efficiently have a WritableBitmap which matches a WPF control pixels 1:1?

Tags: c#, wpf, writablebitmap

I'm using WritableBitmap to draw fast 2d graphics in WPF.

The problem is, my WritableBitmap does not match the pixel size of the Image control 1:1. When I try to make a new WritableBitmap based on size-change events of the Image control, the performance is terrible.

How can I render a WPF control's pixels 1:1 with a WritableBitmap?

You can see both WPF and Windows.Forms versions of [my code on github](https://github.com/jeske/SoundLevelMonitor).

The application is a tiny mini-app called SoundLevelMonitor, which monitors audio levels of applications and paints a continuously moving graph with a legend. Below is a screenshot of the Windows.Forms version. The WPF version is basically the same, except the Image is a fixed size and stretched to fit the window.

[image]

Before I started using WritableBitmap, I tried using UIElement, but the drawing performance was horrible. One problem is that triggering repaint requires `InvalidateVisual()` which causes a slow re-layout. The other problem is that drawing text with DrawingContext is extremely slow.

So I found this [suggestion to write to WriteableBitmap using GDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88488/getting-a-drawingcontext-for-a-wpf-writeablebitmap/797519#797519), and it actually works really well, and is SUPER fast.  (the WPF version feels more responsive than the windows forms version!)

However, the WriteableBitmap is a fixed-sized backingstore which WPF is scaling  up to fit in the Image control. I want the WriteableBitmap to be a 1:1 pixel backing store for the control, even when the control is resized.

I tried to use both `OnRender` and `LayoutUpdated` to trigger creating a new size-matched WriteableBitmap, but both of them were incredibly slow. Probably because setting Image.Source is triggering a relayout.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

My biggest discovery is that I don't need to use a bitmap to get the results I want. I can create a `DrawingGroup` as a backingstore, draw this to the drawing context during OnRender, and then still update it later whenever I want.

```
DrawingGroup backingStore = new DrawingGroup();

protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext) {      
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);            

    Render(); // put content into our backingStore
    drawingContext.DrawDrawing(backingStore);
}

// I can call this anytime, and it'll update my visual drawing
// without ever triggering layout or OnRender()
private void Render() {            
    var drawingContext = backingStore.Open();
    Render(drawingContext);
    drawingContext.Close();            
}
```

---

I also learned that `StreamGeometry` with `Freeze()` is notably faster than other drawing methods, as it optimizes for no animation.

---

Related to my bitmap attempts -- the correct way to be notified when the Image Control size changes is to listen to `SizeChanged`, which fires only when the control changes size. In this event handler, I had to make a new WriteableBitmap of size `Image.RenderSize` and assign it to the Image.Source.

Also, in the Image Control instantiation, I had to set it to `Stretch="Fill"` to cause it to fill it's containing box completely, instead of maintaining the image's aspect ratio.

`LayoutUpdated` is fired every time the control content updates, which is what was causing my original performance problem.

I also found that I can use `RenderTargetBitmap` instead of `WriteableBitmap`, and then I can issue WPF drawing commands to it, instead of using a GDI Graphics context.

..and I can catch the `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event to cause it to be redrawn every frame.